# Ranking users as numbers between 1 and 10

Tags: real-analysis

```
+-------+--------+----------+
| likes | shares | comments |
+-------+--------+----------+
| 2     | 3      | 1        |
+-------+--------+----------+
| 0     | 0      | 1        |
+-------+--------+----------+
| 20    | 100    | 4        |
+-------+--------+----------+
```

The above table represents stats about users, thousands of them.
The strongest user is the one with the highest `sum(likes + shares + comments)`
I want to rank the users between 1-10 with fractions if needed.
How can I normalize each row to be a number between 1 - 10.
If it helps. I calculate it in a programing language... (nodejs).

Thakns

Comment: I don't see how this is about real analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each user, you can define the proto-score of the user as the sum of all likes, shares and comments.

Then, define the score of the user as the proto-score of the user, divided by the max proto-score overa all users, and multiplied by 10.

So, in your case above, the proto-scores of the users are $6, 1, 124$, and the scores are $10\cdot\frac{6}{124},10\cdot\frac{1}{124},10\cdot\frac{124}{124}$.

---

With a formula, if you have users $u_1,\cdots u_n$, and $l(u), s(u), c(u)$ is the number of likes, shares and comments of user $u$, then the total score of user $u_i$ is

$$10\cdot \frac{l(u)+s(u)+c(u)}{\max_{i\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}}\{l(u_i)+s(u_i)+c(u_i)\}}.$$

---

A python program calculating the scores would be something like

```
scores = [likes(user) + shares(user) + comments(user) for user in users]
max_proto_score = max(scores)
return [10 * score / max_proto_score for score in scores]
```

Comment: Thank you. can you please explain whats behinde the mothods, `likes()`, `scores()` and `comments()`? I assume by `scores()` you meant `shares()`

Comment: @SexyMF yes, shares. `likes(user)` is the number of likes the user made. Same with `shares` and `scores`. How exactly the method is implemented depends on how exactly the data is stored, but it's also not the point of my answer (since that's not really where the math happens :) )